# Why UINavigation blink black

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Here is the code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

[image]

Comment: you have to set   self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;

Comment: Have you try to run with different simulator and with lower OS like 9.2?

Comment: i have solved the problem, thank you for your answer! >_<

Answer (score 0):

ah, I have solved that problem. 
In my AppDelegate.m, when i initialized the UIWindow, i didn't set the UIWindow's backgroundColor or its rootViewController's backgroundColor. So setting one of the two backgroundColor will OK.
When the view who was pushed to the top doesn't well-initialized(In method of "viewDidLoad", there are no other codes but "super viewDidLoad"), the black color will occur, just like this:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgM08.gif)

Thank all the guys that answered my question. My English is not good, haha, and this was my first asking, thank you!